# Projection error of stereo calibration difference

Tags: python, opencv, camera-calibration, stereoscopy

I executed the stereo calibrate function of OpenCV to calculate the rotation matrix and translation vector between two cameras. Then, I printed out the RMS error. But when I execute the code using the same parameters in another system, I get two different error values.
I'm asking about the reason for having two different error values.

[Root mean square error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WTkAU.png)

```
for i, fname in enumerate(imagesL):
        Lframe = cv.imread(imagesL[i])
        Rframe = cv.imread(imagesR[i])
        Limg = cv.cvtColor(Lframe, cv.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
        Rimg = cv.cvtColor(Rframe, cv.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
        Lframe = cv.undistort(Limg, LcameraMatrix, LdistCoeffs, None, LnewCameraMatrix)
        Rframe = cv.undistort(Rimg, RcameraMatrix, RdistCoeffs, None, RnewCameraMatrix)
        #cv.imwrite("undistorted/L{}".format(imagesR[i][15:]),Rframe)
        #cv.imwrite("undistorted/{}.png".format(i),Lframe)
        #ImageView.frame = Rframe
        #ImageView.frame = Lframe
        retL, Lcorners = getImagePoints(Lframe,boardWidth, boardHeight)
        retR, Rcorners = getImagePoints(Rframe, boardWidth, boardHeight)
        if retL and retR:
            objectPoints.append(objp)
            LimagePoints.append(Lcorners)
            RimagePoints.append(Rcorners)

        #STEREO CALIBRATE
    print("calculating stereo paramaeters")
    rms, K1, D1, K2, D2, R,T, E, F = cv.stereoCalibrate(objectPoints, LimagePoints, RimagePoints, LcameraMatrix, LdistCoeffs, RcameraMatrix, RdistCoeffs, (Lframe.shape[0], Lframe.shape[1]), criteria=criteria, flags=flags)

    print("root mean square erro:\n")
    print("rmse = {}".format(rms))
```

Comment: The reason may be that they are two different systems. We don't know anything about those systems and what you are actually doing, so we can't tell you why you get different results.

Comment: I was calibrating stereo cameras following [this](https://docs.opencv.org/master/da/de9/tutorial_py_epipolar_geometry.html)

Comment: Please [edit] your question and include a [mre].

Comment: The question is still unclear for me. What do you mean with "using the same parameters in another system"?

Comment: @Grillteller same inputs (images, intrinsic matrix)